# Validate original app purchase

Tags: ios, app-store, iad

is there a way to detect if a user has payed for an app already?

I want to integrate iAd in an app which is sold already - now i want not to show the ads to the old users when they upgrade.

edited: the new version of the app will be free then!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily done by [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

When the user pay add a value to NSUserDefault like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"Paid"];
```

When you need to check whether he paid or not:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Paid"])
{
  //paid user
}
else
{
 //Not paid user can show iAd
}
```

Comment: that's the solution from Nils via code - thanks! I will choose this one then - did you use sth. like this already in your own projects?

Comment: Remember that if the app is ever deleted, or the phone ever flushed, the ads will reappear.

Comment: @user1719539: I have used it in my project, when the user deletes the app, the issue mentioned by Nils Munch will occur. For avoiding that you can check the validation receipt of inapp purchase at the very first run of the application.

Comment: me once again - so i have to put this standardUserDefaults first onto my current app - and the check i can just put into the upgraded-app then? So i need to upload two binaries in row...

Comment: StandardUserDefault is a built in feature. If you upgraded to latest version, then also you get the same user default. Updating the app won't erase the data.

Comment: so i have to comment this out then in the upgrade-version, isn't it? [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"Paid"];

Comment: In the upgraded version you can don't need to remove the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, unfortunately. You shouldn't add adverts to a product that was once paid for, sorry. Consider releasing a free version of your app with adverts alongside the paid version.

Comment: And Apple can live with that that there will be the same app with the same content? I do not want to hide any features in that free version then.

Answer (score 0):

You can run validation of reciepts on inapp purchases, but I have yet to see anyone make initial purchase validation work. (Would be a blessing for the anti-piracy world if it did.)

Comment: No way to do detect it via code like a switch instead of unsing an inapp-purchase? Because some guys already bought it.

Comment: Im afraid not. The app binary have no idea if its price once bought. The closest thing you can do is set a standarduserdefault on the existing app, and if the upgrade contains this pref, the ads will be removed. Unfortunately, flushing the app will kill any standarduserdefaults.

Comment: that makes sense - btw: what means flushing exactly - deleting? I guess if a user deletes it he will not install it soon again... ;-)

Comment: Flushing : Either deleting the app manually, or the app being lost if a phone is reset to factory setting. Whatever would make the app "disappear" from the home screen.

Comment: ok - thanx - seems the only way until now so far